# How to investigate why Git deleted some code

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

We just had a problem with an automatic merge commit where some lines have been deleted that should not have been deleted. We then fixed it manually, but it just happened again.

We currently have a more SVN-like Git workflow: There is only one branch everyone should commit to ("development"), and we only use the a "release" branch to "freeze" the current development state, fix the major issues there, and merge that into "master" as soon as it's stable enough. However, the problematic merges were performed to merge a local branch into the remote development branch, so there was no "real" branch that got merged.

I checked out the versions of the merge commit's parent commits of a file where code was deleted, but just as you'd expect: in one the lines were there, and in the other they were not.

My problem is that I have no idea why Git would choose to delete those lines, and I also don't know where to look for information about that. Can this be determined somehow, or can someone already tell me what might have lead to the decision to delete code? How can we prevent that from happening (other than manually merging)?

Side note: 
Most people in that repository use the Git client build into Visual Studio (versions 2015 and 2017), and I think everyone who was participating in the problem happening (the creators of the parent commits of the merge commit) is using that client.

Comment: Stop using git like svn. It’s only going to cause confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I think we should start by clarifying something.

> the problematic merges were performed to merge a local branch into the remote development branch

Merges always occur locally, and the normal "pull-then-push" workflow would by default merge the remote development branch into the local branch.  I assume that's what happened and that the phrasing here is just a bit off, so if that's not he case please clarify what process you're using to combine local work with remote work.

> So there was no "real" branch that got merged.

This is at best half true, and not as meaningful as you might think.  Again assuming the normal pull-to-push workflow for sharing a branch, the developer merged *into* a real branch (their local branch); let's call that "ours".  The work to be merged in ("theirs") was specified in terms of a remote branch reference, but that's fine; "theirs" can be pretty much anything you want integrated into "ours".

But ok, why are lines being deleted?  You noted that when you look at the merge parents, one has the lines and the other does not.  That makes sense, but now we need to know about a third commit, called the "merge base".

```
O - A - B - M <--(development)
 \         /
  C - D - E
```

Before the merge `origin/development` was at `B` and the user's local branch (`development`?) was at `E`.  One of these had the lines, the other did not.  Well, git is going to find a "merge base" - usually just the most recent commit "reachable" (by parent pointers) from both `B` and `E`.  That's `O` in the above diagram.

Does `O` have the lines in question?

If no, then git thinks "one of the parents added these lines; so I should add them to the result".

But if yes, then git thinks "one of the parents has made no change to these lines, and the other has deleted them; so I should delete them from the result".

So it sounds like you would've expected the lines *not* to be in the merge base, but they were.  The most common reasons that would happen have to do with the use of `git revert` - especially to revert a merge if it was "done too soon".  But that's just one possibility.

That's about all the general information I can give; to give more advice on how this might be happening or how to avoid it, would require more specifics, and from my perspective it's not even clear what I'd have to ask (or whether it would be more detail than you can share).  Hopefully understanding this bit of additional info about how merge results are calculated will provide some insight.

Answer (score 0):

> We just had a problem with an automatic merge commit where some lines
>   have been deleted that should not have been deleted. We then fixed it
>   manually, but it just happened again.

IMHO it looks like there was a conflict (or conflicts), which was/were not properly resolved before the merge. Automatic merge can only happen when changes you have do not interfere (e.g., are in different files) with those that are currently on the remote repository *but* are simultaneously not reflected in your current working tree.

> We currently have a more SVN-like Git workflow: There is only one
>   branch everyone should commit to ("development"), and we only use the
>   a "release" branch to "freeze" the current development state, fix the
>   major issues there, and merge that into "master" as soon as it's
>   stable enough. However, the problematic merges were performed to merge
>   a local branch into the remote development branch, so there was no
>   "real" branch that got merged.

So let me get this straight – there is origin/development, origin/master (for production) and origin/release (for as you've called it: *freeze*). Everyone is working locally and when your work is done you would push your changes to the origin/development? If that's the case, this is what might have happened (A - Alice, B - Bob):

1. **A** clones or pulls current origin/dev locally.
2. **A** is working hard on a new feature...
3. Meanwhille **B** clones or pulls current origin/dev locally 'cause he needs to make a quick fix in the READ.ME file.
4. **B** finishes his work and he makes commit & push so his fix is currently on origin/dev.
5. **A** finally finished her work (and the feature works great BTW). Now she wants to commit and push. However the state of the origin/dev has changed, so now:

   - if she didn't touch the **B's** files – she can pull (the changed READ.ME file) and then push the merged changes.
   - if she made a change to any of the **B's** files (and esp. in lines where B made changes) there is a conflict and git does not know who's version is OK? A's, B's or even both?

So now, if Alice resolve the conflict taking her version of the file and marks the conflict as resolved and then pushes, the READ.ME on origin/dev will lose B's changes. And this is what might have happened in your case.

What she has to do is to manually resolve this conflict. Because now, after B's changes her code might not be needed after all, or on the other hand, she might need to combine their changes into a mutual change.

> My problem is that I have no idea why Git would choose to delete those
>   lines, and I also don't know where to look for information about that.

As far as I know, Git on it's own won't delete any part of the code if it was not told to. Maybe someone pushing the changes just took theirs and overwrote the code previously present in the branch. Like in this picture:

[image]

> Can this be determined somehow, or can someone already tell me what
>   might have lead to the decision to delete code? How can we prevent
>   that from happening (other than manually merging)?

When your whole team works on the same files and you are pushing it to a single development branch manual merge is a must sooner or later.

> Side note: Most people in that repository use the Git client build
>   into Visual Studio (versions 2015 and 2017), and I think everyone who
>   was participating in the problem happening (the creators of the parent
>   commits of the merge commit) is using that client.

As I mainly use WebStorm as my primary IDE and sometimes SourceTree to browse through our git repository, unfortunately I have a little knowledge about git client in VS 2015/17. Those links may however be helpful:

[Resolve merge conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/vsts/git/tutorial/merging?tabs=visual-studio)

[Using Git for .NET](https://blogs.endjin.com/2014/06/using-git-for-net-development-part-4-resolving-merge-conflicts/)

I hope it threw some light on your problem.